# How can I use a web service from local WSDL file?

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio, wsdl

I have been given a WSDL file from a provider and I have added it as a Service Reference to my C# project in Visual Studio 2013.

I can see the relevant classes I need but when I call the functions on them nothing is transmitting from my program.  I have configured Wireshark to listen but no data is coming from my program when I run it.

Where in Visual Studio can I see the IP address/URL that the web service is trying to connect to?  At some point I assume it establishes a HTTP connection, where can I see this code to check the URL/IP address?

Answer (score 0):

The WSDL file does not contain the address of the service endpoint. You probably created a Service Reference or a Web Reference, which has created a client class for you. If you instantiate this client (lets call it `ExampleClient`) with the default constructor:

```
var serviceCLient = new ExampleClient();
```

Then the URI will be the path of the WSDL file you imported. This mostly works fine if you import a generated WSDL file file the actual service URI, but in your case, you need to tell it where the service is running. You can either pass the service URI in the constructor:

```
var serviceCLient = new ExampleClient("http://example.com/service/endpoint");
```

Or edit your `app.config` or `web.config` (depending on project type). It will have something like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="C:\path\to\your.wsdl" etc etc etc... /> 
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And you should change the `address` attribute there.

For old style web references, you can right click on the reference in Visual Studio (under your project in the `Web References` folder, and select "properties". The properties screen contains a "Web Reference Url" which you can edit to point to the actual service URI.